# Animated gifs in QMovie

Tags: qt, animation, gif

I'm displaying an animated gif in my application by creating a QLabel, and setting the movie as a QMovie.  The problem I'm having is that when the gif is displayed, any part of the image that stays a constant color throughout the animation shows up as the background color.  I hope I'm explaining that clearly.  Here's the code I'm using to create the animation if that helps:

```
rewardLabel=new QLabel();
rewardLabel->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::BlankCursor));
rewardLabel->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
rewardLabel->hide();
string movieTemp="animations/"+animationFiles[animationIndex];
QString movieFile(movieTemp.c_str());
rewardMovie=new QMovie(movieFile);
rewardLabel->setMovie(rewardMovie);
```

Let me know if I need to explain the situation better.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `QWidget`s [window attributes](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum).  I believe the ones you're interested in are:

```
Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent
Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground
Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground
```

There might be a couple of [widget flags](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) of interest too, but I think they've all been moved to flags in Qt-4.